# Get the running total of a column filtered by month and year

Tags: mysql, joomla

I have a MySQL database table called user_inputs with userId(str), year(int), month(int) and input(int) columns.

I need to get the last 12 months of record per user, and get the sum of the input column.

So far I came up with the following:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp 
AS (SELECT *, CAST(CONCAT(`year`, '-', `month`, '-01' ) AS DATE) AS `NewDate` FROM `user_inputs`);

SELECT `userId`, SUM(`input`) AS `running_total` FROM temp 
WHERE `userId` = 266 
AND  `NewDate` BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('2018', '01', '01'), '%Y%m%d') 
AND LAST_DAY(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('2018', '12', '01'), '%Y%m%d'));
```

Is there a way this two statements could be simplified and combined into one, without having to create a temporary table? The goal is to be able to filter the results using a beginning month/year and ending month/year combinations and get the sum of inputs from the result.

Note: I've decided to just add a generated column that combines the month and year columns.

Comment: You know the select is invalid ANSI SQL right? Mixing non aggregated columns with aggregated function is not allowed in ANSI SQL.. MySQL allows with because it extends the ANSI GROUP BY.. When the server is running sql_mode ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY this query will fail..

Comment: Because the query seams to be ANSI SQL invalid and can generated invalid results i advice you to read [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) and provide us with example data and expected results.

Comment: Consider storing years and months as a single entity e.g.: 2018-11-01

Comment: Use the Joomla query builder API if you are doing it from inside Joomla.

Comment: I am imagining a very simple solution here.  Please provide a usable sqlfiddle demo link, so that I can test my solution before posting.  I don't need thousands of rows of data, just enough to play with from scatterred users, years, months.  Will you want to know how to write the query with Joomla's query builder methods?